# Cannot bind to resource in my style wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resources

this is my style:

```
   <Style x:Key="someStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#BB252525"/>                                  
    </Style>
```

That code works fine but I actually need to bind the background color to this resource:

```
<Color x:Key="MenuBackground">#BB252525</Color>
```

And when I do this:

```
 <Style x:Key="someStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
       <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuBackground}"/>                                   
    </Style>
```

I get the following error:

[image]

How could I set the background property equal to the resource MenuBackground. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind to a `Brush`, not a `Color` as `Background` is a `Brush` property.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuBackground" Color="#BB252525"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

`Application.Resources` could be `Control.Resources` or other .Resources respectively.

Comment: But how could I create a brush resource? maybe I am missing a reference?